# How to modify object from a lambda expression body used in Linq Extension method?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want the side effect when using lambda expression with `Select` extension method, something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SyntaxExperiment {

    public class Program {
        static void Main() {
            var list = new List<int>();
            var results = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }
                .Select(
                    i => {
                        list.Add(i);
                        return i;
                    }   
                );
            Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

The code above outputs:

```
0
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LINQ code is not actually executing because it's just an `IEnumerable<int>` that has no reason to execute. You can force it to execute like this:

```
var results = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }
    .Select(i => {
        list.Add(i);
        return i;
    })
    .ToList();
```

To put it another way, an *enumerable* doesn't do anything until you *enumerate* through it, and `ToList`, by forcing the data into a collection, causes that enumeration.

Comment: And the obligitory, "you should not be counting on side effects when running linq queries, that's not what it was designed for."

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is built on functional programming principles, so while it can be done it's not really designed for mutating data or doing things by side effect.

What you want to do (assuming the real code is more complicated than your example!) is Select the necessary data and then convert the IEnumerable into a List.

```
var results = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Select(i => i).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Foreach` like below

```
static void Main()
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    var results = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    results.ToList().ForEach(i => list.Add(i));
    Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
}
```

Comment: ForEach isn't actually an extension method on IEnumerable/part of LINQ - keeping in line with the functional programming principles. The reason you need to call the .ToList() is because ForEach is on List<T>.